# How to plot a hole in a hole in a hole?

Tags: graphing-functions, geometric-topology

There is an image from this [book.(page 22)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098705)

I want to plot it, but I don't know  equation of this surface.

[image]

Anyone have an idea about it and how to plot it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: while interesting, I feel like this is more of a math question on how to parametrize that surface

Comment: You might look at the parametric plot of a Klein bottle, it has similar properties (not the same though).
See this [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118957/my-3d-plot-of-a-klein-bottle-doesnt-look-right).

Comment: You could get a shape of the right topology at least by using `RegionUnion`, `RegionDifference` etc. on a `Sphere`, some `Cylinder`'s, and a torus (as an `ImplicitRegion` perhaps).

Comment: I could not find anything relevant but may be these links are useful. http://www.kleinbottle.com/gallery/Hole-through-a-Hole-in-a-Hole http://www.kleinbottle.com/gallery/Spivak_Hole_Pix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8Rxep2Mkp8                       Especially the video.

Comment: I admire everyone's (well, everyone else's) restraint in not mentioning the relevant meme here.

Answer (score 8):

I was planning to answer this on Mathematica.stackexchange but it was migrated before I finished :(

Fortunately it still asks for Mathematica coding tips and additionally my answer contains some formulas so it should be on topic :)

I imagined I will give a neat example of region related features but it is quicker to write parameters manually than to wait for `TransformedRegion` with `Scaling/RotationTransform` to return.

```
torus = ImplicitRegion[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - .7)^2 + z^2 < .2^2, {x, y, z}];

tube = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < .1 z^2 + .1, {x, y, z}];

smallTube =  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + z^2 < .05 (y - 1.2)^2 + .01 && .6 <= y <= 2.5, 
   {x, y, z}
];

RegionPlot3D[
    Fold[
        RegionDifference
      , Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2]
      , {torus, tube, smallTube
          , TransformedRegion[smallTube, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1, 0}]]
        }
    ]
  , BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]
  , PlotPoints -> 60
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! But I think it deserves also to be in Mathematica.stackexchange:-)!

Comment: I cast the final vote on this migration so blame me.  Sorry about that.  But if it made you get your feet wet over here on Mathematics maybe it's not a bad thing; this community can only be enriched by your presence.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard so much sugar :) But thanks, and you are right, it helped me to get wet which was something I was hesitant about :)